# Problemas al leer archivo Excel SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

El error retornado por la setencia es:

> Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1 sql server 2012 Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
                ,'Excel 12.0 Xml;Database=\\path\archivo_excel.xls;HDR=YES'
                ,'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Hice lo que indicaban en este blog:
http://visakhm.blogspot.cl/2013/12/how-to-solve-microsoftaceoledb120-error.html

Y persiste el problema, por lo que he visto esta página no es la única con dicho tema, hay varias que indican inclusive la misma solución.

¿Alguien tiene alguna solución?

Answer (score 1):

Depende de para que necesites leer el excel, porque si lo que deseas es cargarlo en SQL Server podrías usar el Management Studio para subirlo a una tabla y ya ahí haces las consultas que ocupes.

[Importar datos de un Hoja de Excel a SQL Server 2008 R2](https://thanksnetwork.wordpress.com/2012/11/12/importar-datos-de-un-hoja-de-excel-a-sql-server-2008-r2/)

O incluso podrías usar paquetes SSIS para importar un excel a SQL Server

[Usando paquetes SSIS para importar datos de MS Excel en una base de datos](http://www.sqlshack.com/es/usando-paquetes-ssis-para-importar-datos-de-ms-excel-en-una-base-de-datos/)

Answer (score 0):

Esta respuesta la he colocado hace unos minutos en otro hilo, pero al final es el mismo problema.

1. Asegúrate que tienes los componentes o drivers de conexión.
2. Debes asignar al servicio de SQL Server un usuario de dominio con privilegios suficientes para usar el recurso de red al que estás intentando conectarte.
3. Ejecuta la consulta que muestro mas adelante.
4. No olvides agregar el login del usuario que creaste para el servicio `SQL Server` con el rol de `sysadmin`.

Esta es la consulta que menciono en el punto #3:

```
use master 
go 
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 
reconfigure 
go 
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1 
reconfigure 
go 
exec sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
go 
exec sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 
go
```

Comment: te recomiendo leer la [ayuda de markdown](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help), allí encontrarás información sobre como publicar correctamente fragmentos de código.

Comment: Si tu Sistema Operativo es de 64 bits creo que también da cierto problema para conectar de esa forma un archivo excel